# Share price less than certain value for 6 consecutive business days or more in the past month

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

This is for MySQL 8.X database.

My requirement is as follows:
If a share price is less than a certain value for 6 consecutive business days or more in the past month then I need to inform the investor.

There will not be any share price on holidays and weekends. So there will not be any data for these days.

For example:
In the below data, the share price is less than 100 for 6 consecutive business days between 14th and 21 Dec 2021. I need to find such shares and the number of days the share price has gone below the target value.

| effective_date | security | market_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 99 |
| 2-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 98 |
| 3-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 97 |
| 6-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 101 |
| 7-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 99 |
| 8-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 98 |
| 9-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 97 |
| 10-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 96 |
| 13-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 102 |
| 14-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 99 |
| 15-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 98 |
| 16-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 97 |
| 17-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 96 |
| 20-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 95 |
| 21-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 99 |
| 22-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 102 |
| 23-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 103 |
| 24-Dec-2021 | STOCKNAME | 114 |

Expected Output:

```
security    number_of_days
STOCKNAME   6
```

Comment: Are your dates really stored in that way?

Comment: Hi Salmon. Data is stored as shown in the sample. There will not be any share price available on weekends and holidays. So there will be gaps in the date. Thank you. Vadi.

Comment: 'not be any share price available on weekends' - then there can't be 6 consecutive business days ? Surely 5 is the max? Please publish your expected result based on the sample data to help clarify.

Comment: What is past month? If today is 28 Dec then does it mean the whole November or just the past 30 days from today?

Comment: Hi Salmon. I have added the expected output above in the question. What is required is the share name and number of days the share price has gone below the target value. Consecutive business days means, working days not including weekends and holidays. So it can be more than 5 days. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Salman. Past month means the past 30 days from today. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem, with the islands being the consecutive days.

You need to assign a unique value to each consecutive group of rows that qualify (ie value < 100) and then count the rows in each group, selecting the max of these:

```
with g as (
    select *,
        Row_Number() over (partition by security order by effective_date)
        - Row_Number() over (partition by security, 
            case when market_price<100 then 1 else 0 end order by effective_date
        ) cnt
    from t
)
select security, Count(*) number_of_days
from g
group by security, cnt
order by number_of_days desc
limit 1
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f095c6684e97b39d124632a16883511d)

Comment: Hi Stu. Thanks a lot for the reply. Let me check this.

Comment: Hi Stu. Your solution is working correctly for the sample data I had given. Thank you very much for the help. Much appreciated. However, I am now trying to get it to work on the full set of data. I will let you know the results. I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks again for the help.